# How to Combine and sort columns? MySQL, CF8, MS Access 2003

Tags: mysql, ms-access, sql-order-by, coldfusion-8

I want to produce an alphabetized list of names produced by adding together two columns of names, columnA, and columnB.

I have tried this:

```
<cfquery name="listAuthors" datasource="hhLibrary">
SELECT title, (a1_Fname + a2_Fname) AS ColumnA, (a1_Lname + a2_Lname) AS ColumnB
FROM books
WHERE ColumnB LIKE '#firstletter#%'
ORDER BY ColumnB
</cfquery>
```

this is the error code:
Too few parameters. Expected 1.

any help greatly appreciated.

oregonHoney

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
select *
from (
    SELECT title, a1_Lname as Name
    FROM books  
    WHERE a1_Lname LIKE '#firstletter#%' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title, a2_Lname as Name
    FROM books  
    WHERE a2_Lname LIKE '#firstletter#%' 
) a
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: i must not have described the issue well enough...what i want to do is extend the column, that is, a1_Lname, so that it further lists all the names in the second column too, THEN alphabetizes this complete, longer list of names.
the code above results in a list of NEW names which have been created by merging the last names of two people together. So now i have "Smithstevens" showing up instead of "smith" then "Stevens"

Answer (score 0):

In Jet/ACE SQL you can't place a WHERE clause or ORDER BY on a field-name alias -- you have to repeat the expression the alias is referring to. So, replace this:

```
  SELECT title, (a1_Fname + a2_Fname) AS ColumnA, (a1_Lname + a2_Lname) AS ColumnB
  FROM books
  WHERE ColumnB LIKE '#firstletter#%'
  ORDER BY ColumnB
```

...with this:

```
  SELECT title, (a1_Fname + a2_Fname) AS ColumnA, (a1_Lname + a2_Lname) AS ColumnB
  FROM books
  WHERE a1_Lname + a2_Lname LIKE '#firstletter#%'
  ORDER BY a1_Lname + a2_Lname
```

If you have Access installed, I strongly encourage you to test your SQL in interactive Access, in the QBE. You would quickly have discovered that this is the case if you'd just tried it within Access.